# Microsoft.Web.Atlas.dll and IIS7 Integrated mode

Tags: iis

I'm moving a website from IIS6 to IIS7 and I can’t get Microsoft.Web.Atlas.dll to work when IIS7 is running in integrated mode. It works fine in classic mode. I just get an unknown error dialog and I can see it's a 500 error on the server. When doing a trace the only information I get is that it's the error is from ManagedPipelineHandler. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're probably aware, `Microsoft.Web.Atlas.dll` was the CTP of the ASP.NET AJAX components (from circa 2005/6). Unfortunately I and probably many others have long disposed of this CTP so I can only speculate as to what may be wrong and some possible fixes:

1. Try adding any Atlas specific handlers and modules to the `<system.webServer>` section of your `web.config` file.
2. If the new server is running 64-bit windows try switching the application pool the site resides in to 32-bit mode.
3. Configure the site's application pool to run ASP.NET 2.0 and not ASP.NET 4.0.
4. Because it's so old and it was a CTP, Atlas may not even be compatible with Integrated Pipeline mode.
5. Consider updating the code to use Microsoft AJAX 2.0 RTM.

Comment: Got it working now by giving it is own application pool running classic mode but I gues I have to go with option 5