# Error 59 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Atlas' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll

I am trying to upgrade a application from .net 2.0 to .net 4.6.1, but it requires 
Microsoft.Web.Atlas and gives me a error when I try to run it. I have tried searching for this Microsoft.Web.Atlas dll on internet but couldn't find it. Can somebody suggest any links where I can download the dll or may be if there is another way to solve this issue?

Error : `<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.Web.Atlas" Namespace="Microsoft.Web.UI.Controls"     TagPrefix="cc2" %>`

Comment: I think this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309715/microsoft-web-atlas-dll-and-iis7-integrated-mode) may be of help for you.

Comment: @ Pilgerstorfer Fran - I tried this already and it seems my issue is different than the above one.

Comment: Took me a while but now I found an older project hosted on [codeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/DateAndTimePicker/DateTimePicker.zip). This one includes *AtlasControlToolkit.dll*